# How to get the Monday date of a week using the week number

Tags: ios

How can I find out the Date of Monday if I pass the week number. For example, I need the Monday of the Week 24 of the year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill out a `NSDateComponents` object with the information you have. Then you can ask the current `NSCalendar` what date corresponds to those components.

```
NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
components.weekday = 2;
components.weekOfYear = 24;
components.year = 2012;
NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents: components];
```

The `weekday` property starts with Sunday = 1.

If you are on OS X 10.7 or newer you should use the property `yearForWeekOfYear` instead of `year`.

Comment: +1 for adding Note:use property 'yearForWeekOfYear' instead of 'year' which worked for me